# Show that the integral $ f(x,y)=1+\int_0^x\int_0^y f(u,v)dudv$ has at most one continuous solution

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Show that the integral $$ f(x,y)=1+\int_0^x\int_0^y f(u,v)dudv$$ has at most one continuous solution for $0 \leq x \leq 1$,$ 0\leq y <1$.

The integral can be written as $$I=1+\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(u,v)dudv.$$

Now if we take $f(u,v)$ to be an integrable function in the given region, certainly, we will get only one continuous solution or outcome.

How to argue in general case?

Suppose $f(u,v) = g(u,v)$,then  $$\iint f(u,v)dudv = \iint g(u,v)dudv.$$ Therefore,  $$1+\iint f(u,v)dudv = 1+\iint g(u,v)dudv.$$ This implies $$f(x,y)=g(x,y).$$ So only one continuous solution.

Is it suitable argument??

Comment: Alas, this argument is wrong at almost every step. One hint: you never used continuity anywhere.

Comment: @JohnHughes,but a function can be integrable even itis not continuous

Comment: True. And dogs sometimes have spots. Neither of these facts has any bearing on this problem.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR The solutions of the integral equation are fixed points of the application   $G(f)=1+\int_0^x \int_0^y f(u,v) du dvu$. You can try to use the fixed point theorem.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR That is not true, even for one variable... Only an exponential can verify that condition.

Comment: FTC tells you $f(x) - f(a) = \int_a^x \boxed{f'(t)}dt$, not  $f(t)$. The condition you give means that $f' = f$, so $f$ is exponential (speaking loosely for now).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, yes it was my typo, a derivative would be outside the integral   i.e., $f(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(t)dt$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f,g$ are continuous solutions of the above. Then, $f-g$ satisfies :
$$
(f-g)(x,y) = \int_{0}^x \int_0^y (f-g)(u,v)dudv
$$

Note that $(f-g)(0,0) = 0$. Note that $f-g$ is continuous on $[0,1]^2$, let its maximum be positive and attained at a point $(t,s)$ where $t \neq 0 , s \neq 0$ (if either is zero, then the function is seen to be zero). Note that $$
(f-g)(t,s) = \int_0^t\int_0^s (f-g)(u,v)dudv \leq_1 \int_0^t \int_0^s (f-g)(t,s) dudv \leq ts (f-g)(t,s) 
$$

Now, suppose $ts < 1$. The above inequality cannot hold looking at the ends, so we have a contradiction. Otherwise, $ts = 1$ at most since $t,s \in [0,1]$, and since equality holds, equality must hold in $\leq_1$. Since the LHS function is dominated pointwise by the RHS function, they must be equal i.e. the function $(f-g)(x,y)$ equals its maximum everywhere. Therefore, it is identically zero, a contradiction to a positive maximum.

In other words, the maximum is zero.

---

Note that this argument crucially requires the domain to be $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. For more general compact domains in $\mathbb R^n$, this kind of uniqueness should hold, only I think you would require Gronwall's inequality (I am not sure of the details, however).

Existence could be shown in two ways that I know of : you could use the Picard-Lindelof iteration , along with patching, or you could study the Volterra operator associated to this linear equation. I think this should work at least on $[0,1]^2$ with possible extension to compact domains.

Comment: Suppose $f(u,v)$ is not continuous then can the solution (integral $\iint f(u,v)dudv$) be continuous  ??

Comment: Ah : that's a nice point. If there is a solution, then in fact by bootstrapping using the equation , any solution must in fact be continuous, being equal to a continuous function. What I mean is this : if $f$ is a measurable bounded function satisfying the conditions, then $f$ equals $\int \int f du dv$, which is absolutely continuous, therefore so is $f$. In fact, I think you can bootstrap (Sobolev space theory?) to show that any solution must be real analytic, and then use power series to do this problem as well.

Comment: In the 2nd line after the main equation,you said $\text{since equality holds}$. Which equality?? Is it the last  relation $\leq $  in that equation?

Comment: Equality holds between the first and last terms of the line. Therefore all the less than or equal signs in the middle must be equal signs.